# Javascript Audio API Visualizer not showing in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, api, audio

So i followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/IBHpSkGZtNM
And a while back (about a year ago or so) it worked. Now however it doesn't visualize anything. The sound plays but thats it.

I changed the old webkit functions to the new ones as i was getting errors. However now i don't have any errors and still nothing shows up.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   div#mp3_player{ width: 500px; height: 60px; background: #000000; padding: 5px; margin: 50px auto;}
   div#mp3_player > div > audio{ width: 500px; background: #000000; float: left;}
   div#mp3_player > canvas{width: 500px; height: 30px; background: #002D3C; float: left;}
  </style>
  <script>
   var audio = new Audio();
   audio.src = "audio/DieForYou-Starset.mp3";
   audio.controls = true;
   audio.loop = true;
   audio.autoplay = false;

   var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
   window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);

   function initMp3Player(){
    document.getElementById("audio_box").appendChild(audio);
    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    canvas = document.getElementById("analyser_renderer");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper()
   }
   function frameLooper(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0 ,canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.fillStyle= "#2DCC70";
    bars = 100;
    for(var i = 0; i < bars; i++){
     bar_x = i * 3;
     bar_width = 2;
     bar_height = -(fbc_array[1] / 2);
     ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="mp3_player">
   <div id="audio_box"></div>
   <canvas id="analyser_renderer"></canvas>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I put everything in the html file because it was easier to post like that. I know it's bad practise.

Note: the sound wont play in the snippet because the audio file is stored locally.

I am also running this trough a local server as just opening the html file would result in `MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/audio/DieForYou-Starset.mp3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate your array with one of the [AnalyserNode methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode#Methods), here you are only creating an empty one.

For example, you can call `analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);` to get the current frequency data.

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
audio.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3";
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = false;

window.onload = initMp3Player;

var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;


function initMp3Player() {
  document.getElementById("audio_box").appendChild(audio);
  context = new AudioContext();
  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  canvas = document.getElementById("analyser_renderer");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  // initialise the Uint8Array only once
  fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  frameLooper()
}

function frameLooper() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.fillStyle = "#2DCC70";
  bars = 100;

  // here fill the Uint8Array with audio data
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
    bar_x = i * 3;
    bar_width = 2;
    bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2); // there was a typo
    ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
  }
}
```

```css
div#mp3_player {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

div#mp3_player>div>audio {
  width: 500px;
  background: #000000;
  float: left;
}

div#mp3_player>canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #002D3C;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="mp3_player">
  <div id="audio_box"></div>
  <canvas id="analyser_renderer"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: ah yeah ofcourse :p the simplest errors are usualy the trickiest ones to detect.